# Wrapping each letter of a string with an HTML tag with jQuery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, split

I need to be able to take a string of text and wrap each letter within that string with an HTML tag e.g. `<i>` or `<span>` (It doesn't matter for now).

I've got this so far, but it's not quite working as I need it to.

The issue I have is that I don't want any `<span>` tags currently in the string to be replaced or changed. If there is a `<span>` already in the string then it should keep any classes it already has or the "test_new" class should be added to the class "test" that's already there.

```js
var words = $("p").text().split("");
$("p").empty();
$.each(words, function(i, v) {
  $("p").append($("<span class='test_new'>").text(v));
});
```

```css
span {
   border: 1px solid red;
}

span.test {
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>This is a <span class="test">test</span> string</p>
```

Essentially after the code runs, the `<span>` should be blue meaning the `<span>` has retained any original classes after the string has been converted.

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: If your string is HTML, then you'll need an HTML parser.  You can't `split` and you can't use `regex` (as HTML is too complicated).

Comment: @freedomn-m Is this not possible to do then? I'm trying to animate each letter on a website for each word. But I can't let it affect HTML inside the string otherwise it will break specific styles for different words inside the string.

Comment: You can parse it then extract the text nodes and then apply split/wrap on the words on those.   Will depend on what level you want to go down to - eg if your `span` has another `span` inside, or there's a `table` etc

Comment: @freedomn-m Thanks, can you point in the right direction on how I can accomplish this? E.g. code examples, stackoverflow posts etc?

Comment: Plenty of solution on SO, just need to go through them to find closest to your requirement: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+wrap+words

Comment: Just out of curiosity... are you trying to create a code/text highlighter? ...In which you want to *skip* some code (or text) that is already highlighted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to filter out to only get text nodes (`node.nodeType === Node` in the example below). To prevent wrapping white space (code indentation) you probably want to filter on that too (`node.nodeValue.trim() !== ""` in the example below).

The filter function in jQuery allows you to do that.

I made a function to wrap each letter of a text with your span tag using the standard map function.

Last by looping over each text node and using the replaceWith jQuery function and our newly created wrapChars function you can wrap all characters of all text nodes.

```js
$('p').contents()
      .filter((i, node) => node.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE && node.nodeValue.trim() !== "")
      .each((i, textNode) => $(textNode).replaceWith(wrapChars($(textNode).text())));

function wrapChars(text) {
  return [...text].map((c) => `<span class="test_new">${c}</span>`).join('');
}
```

```css
span.test_new {
    border: 1px solid red;
}

span.test {
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>This is a <span class="test">test</span> string</p>
```

Comment: As this will likely be of use for future similar questions, I'll add the note:   To make this work for *words* instead of *characters*, replace `[...text].map` with `text.split(" ").map` and `.join('')` with `.join(' ')`